# Modifications to WCF service consumed by Java clients

Tags: java, wcf

What is the best way to introduce a new DataMember in a webservice(WCF) without affecting the consuming Java clients?

This is the issue we have: There are two teams(Java) that consume our webservice(WCF). We have got a new requirement from one of the above team that would need introduction of a new DataMember in our webservice, but the other team neednot have it.

We were thinking of adding the new DataMember as Nullable type or setting [IsRequired=false] in the data contract for that DataMember , but it seems Java doesnt support Nullable types and SOAP doesnt recognize the [IsRequired] tag to ignore it.

Any suggestions please, to make this change to our service so that only one team would need to make the required changes without affecting the other ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "new field"? Is it a new operation or a new node in request/response some operation?

Comment: why are you calling "new field" ? a new property in the result ?

Comment: Any pointers please?...The lack of answers indicates that there is no other route; that there would be modifications required for both Java teams??